# How can I use the input parameter value passed to a JavaScript function into the popup opened by this JS function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am not so into **PHP** and **JavaScript** and I have the following problem trying to pass a value from a main page to a popup page (defined into this main page).
I try to explain my situation in details:

I have an **account.php** page containing this link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="doRemoveBooking();">
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
</a>
```

Clicking on this link it is performed the **doRemoveBooking()** JavaScript function that is defined in the same page into this block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //metodo richiamato al click del bottone "RIVENDI"
    function doRemoveBooking(id){
        console.info("Into doRemoveBooking");

        $('.popUpRemoveBooking').magnificPopup({
            items: {
                src: '#remove-booking-popup'
            }
            // (optionally) other options
        }).magnificPopup('open');
    }
</script>
```

that opens a popup defined at the end of the dame **account.php** page by this div element:

```
<div class="popUpRemoveBooking">
    <div id="remove-booking-popup" class=" white-popup-block mfp-hide">
        <div class="fluid-container">
            <div class="row">
                <h2><?php echo $texts['CANCEL_BOOKING'] ?></h2>

                <p>Sei veramente sicuro di voler cancellare la prenotazione?</p>
                <?php echo $id_booking; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This popup is correctly opened but I obtain an error message when it try to render this line:

```
<?php echo $id_booking; ?>
```

I know that it is wrong. As you can see my JavaScript function take an id as parameter:

```
doRemoveBooking(id)
```

How can I print this **id** received as input parameter from the JavaScript function used to open the popup in the popup body? (instead the wrong ). What is a smart and neat way to do it?

Comment: What error message do you get fromt the `echo`-line?

Comment: @modsfabio the error message is a PHP error because the : id_booking  variable is undefined. It is normal I have to replace it using JavaScript I suppose

Comment: you getting undfined index ? on `$id_booking`?

Comment: Why not define it? So you don't need to pass the id using JavaScript. Or do you have multiple IDs on that page?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile yes, it was used in a previous version when I had the popup in another file and I reach it submitting, now I have to do it using JavaScript and I have to use the value received as input parameter by my Js function

Comment: Maybe you need to get the `$id_booking` in your loop or something: `<a href="#" onclick="doRemoveBooking(<?php echo $id_booking; ?>);">` that depends on how the rest of the page looks like I'm just gessing that link is created by a loop.

Comment: @modsfabio yes, I have multiple id in this page. So I have to use the one related to the clicked one (using JS)

Comment: I think @xander suggestion could work

Comment: You need to understand that PHP happens on the server and javascript happens on the client. At the time when javascript happens on the clientside, all the PHP code is already 'done' so you cannot mix those two. You have to use AJAX to send info to the server, or you need to use javascript and not PHP to get the value in the popup.

Comment: @Dellirium Exactly I only want to use JavaScript to use the id valuereceived from my doRemoveBooking(id) function into the popup, but how can I do it?

Comment: Replace `<?php echo $id_booking; ?>` for example with a `<span>` and in  `doRemoveBooking(id)` you change the `<span>`-content (using jQuery) to `id`. That will work.

Comment: @AndreaNobili did you try my suggestion? if that doesn't work we need to see the surrounding code of your `<a href="#" onclick="doRemoveBooking();">
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
</a>`

Comment: @modsfabio can you explain me better?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<?php echo $id_booking; ?>` with `<span id="bookingID"></span>`

Then replace the content of that `<span>` in your function:

```
function doRemoveBooking(id){
    console.info("Into doRemoveBooking");

    $('#bookingID').html(id); // <---------------- Add this line

    $('.popUpRemoveBooking').magnificPopup({
        items: {
            src: '#remove-booking-popup'
        }
        // (optionally) other options
    }).magnificPopup('open');
}
```

Don't forget to call `doRemoveBooking(id)` with the correct booking-id !

Comment: But why not just generate the correct `doRemoveBooking(id)` call for every link with php instead of using an extra placeholder, that's what I'd do. But as I said in my comments without more of the code we can only guess where the `$id_booking` is coming from.

Comment: `$id_booking` does not exist as he said. He want's a dynamic popup, so we need a placeholder.

Comment: As I understand it does not exists at the position he tried to use it, but it might exist somewhere else inside a loop (my guess) where the bookings are listed or something.

Comment: He wrote: `it was used in a previous version`. So I thought it's not used anymore in the current version.. We will wait for his answer :) But in this case he just has to add `$id_booking` to the function call like `doRemoveBooking(<?php echo $id_booking; ?>)`

Comment: ok maybe, but there has to be a way to get the `id_booking` at the php side of the code, hwo else would he access it..

Comment: In this way doesn't work. The span having id=bookingID is empty

Comment: @AndreaNobili Do you pass an `id` to your function?

Comment: yes, and it is preinted in the console by the console.info statment

Comment: Can you change the console output to see if the `id` is passed? `console.info("Into doRemoveBooking, ID: " + id);`

Comment: @modsfabio yes it show the numeric id of the clicked element

Comment: Hm, you've got me stumped. I don't see a problem why it should not work. You can add a test-span somewhere else on the page and give it a try. Maybe the popup somehow blocks the content of that span.

Comment: The question is how is the `ìd` set when you call it like `onclick="doRemoveBooking();"` (clearly no id is passed to that function)?? Or is your posted code not the correct one you're using?